# Remove a shadow from all lines

Tags: vba, excel, line

I've just inherited an Excel app that draws an org chart. Each shape is connected by a `Line`

However, I need to remove the shadow that is drawn when each line is added. How do I get a collection of `Lines` so that I can do something like

```
Line.Shadow.Transparency = 1.0
```

I'm a bit of a vba newbie :-)

Comment: A good start point would be to do it in Excel recording it as a macro, then inspect the code and apply accordingly

Comment: Can I record a macro that will select all lines only ?

Comment: 1. iterate through all shapes, 2. test if shape is line, 3. do code, 4. loop.

Comment: Do any of the SmartArt Styles which you can apply to the org chart have lines without shadows? I'm using Excel 2016 for Windows, and none of the styles have shadows on the lines, so I suspect you're using Mac Excel, which includes shadows on all of its charts by default.

Comment: I'd also use `Line.Shadow.Visible = False` instead of messing with transparency.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick - it loops through all shapes, checks if they're a line, then removes the shadow.

```
Sub test()

Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = ActiveSheet

Dim shapeObj
For Each shapeObj In ActiveSheet.Shapes
    If shapeObj.Type = 9 Then
        Dim objName$
        objName = shapeObj.Name
        ws.Shapes.Range(Array(objName)).Shadow.Visible = msoFalse
    End If
Next shapeObj

End Sub
```

Edit: Turns out, per OP, the shapes are grouped, so he used this to get it:

```
Sub RemoveLineShadows()
For Each Shp In ORG.Shapes
    If Shp.Type = msoGroup Then
        For X = 1 To Shp.GroupItems.Count
            If Shp.GroupItems(X).Type = msoLine Then
                Shp.GroupItems(X).Shadow.Transparency = 1
            End If
        Next X
    End If
Next Shp
End Sub
```

Comment: I'm not sure how this is going to format but it turned out all of the shapes were grouped so I went with this that works. Thank you for the pointer though. Much appreciated.                                                                    Sub RemoveLineShadows()
For Each Shp In ORG.Shapes
If Shp.Type = msoGroup Then
For X = 1 To Shp.GroupItems.Count
 If Shp.GroupItems(X).Type = msoLine Then
 Shp.GroupItems(X).Shadow.Transparency = 1#
 End If
 Next X
 End If
Next Shp
End Sub

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub qqq()
Dim x As Shape
    For Each x In ActiveSheet.Shapes
        x.Shadow.Visible = msoFalse
    Next
End Sub
```